# How to detect collision between objects in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm making a sidescrolling game in Pygame, and if the fox sprite collides with the tree, it is supposed to print "COLLIDE". But it doesn't work. How can I fix this to detect collision between the fox and the tree? Here's the code:

```
if foxsprite1 > xtree  and foxsprite1 < xtree + treewidth or foxsprite1 + treewidth > xtree and foxsprite1 + treewidth < xtree + treewidth:
        print ("COLLIDE")
```

xtree is the x coordinate of the tree, treewidth is the width of the tree, and foxsprite1 is the fox.

Comment: keep object position and size as `pygame.Rect()` and then you can use `if fox_rect.colliderect(tree_rect): print("COLLIDE")`

Comment: http://pygame.org/wiki/QuadTree

Answer (score 3):

Keep object position and size as [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

```
fox_rect = pygame.Rect(fox_x, fox_y, fox_width, fox_height)
tree_rect = pygame.Rect(tree_x, tree_y, tree_width, tree_height)
```

and then you can use

```
if fox_rect.colliderect(tree_rect): 
     print("COLLIDE")
```

`Rect()` is very usefull. You can use it to blit

```
screen.blit(fox_image, fox_rect)
```

You can use it to center object on screen

```
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

fox_rect.center = screen_rect.center
```

or to keep object on the screen (and it can't leave screen)

```
if fox_rect.right > screen_rect.right:
    fox_rect.right = screen_rect.right

if fox_rect.left < screen_rect.left:
    fox_rect.left = screen_rect.left
```

or simpler

```
fox_rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

see: [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/) and [Example code and programs](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38)

Comment: Thanks, it works but it detects the collision way too soon, before the tree is even touching the fox, it prints "COLLIDE" and then goes away. I'm thinking maybe it's the scrolling background that affects the collision detection? The fox_x is 200, fox_y is 250, fox_width is 250, fox_height is 200. The tree_x, tree_y, tree_width and tree_height are all 300. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you have image with margin then you can create second, smaller rect `fox_collide_rect`, `tree_collide_rect`  and use it only to check collision. When you move `fox_rect` then you can move `fox_collide_rect` using (for example) `fox_collide_rect.center = fox_rect.center`