# Pygame: Stop manually moved object before it's going to hit something

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to recreate this Classic Football game from back in the day in pygame and it's starting to get a little complicated for me.

If you run the program, you'll see I've drawn everything out and have a main movable player (QB) with other static sitting players who can't move yet.

I'm going to eventually have to move every opposing player individually and randomly towards the QB, I started working on that by establishing functions and what not for them but first want to figure out how to for example...

### -

-

There's the line, you'll notice in game, when you move forward towards line, it turns the QB white, I need to make it where the QB turns white in his sitting place if that makes sense. So when you press right arrow towards line, he doesn't move forward but the game recognizes that he is trying to and is tackled in place.

I just don't understand how to even make it do that... Tried a couple different things that haven't worked.

You don't have to do all the code for me but just give me a little guidance.

```
import pygame, sys

# Colors
black   =   (0,0,0)
white   =   (255,255,255)
red     =   (255,0,0)
field   =   (17,0,0)
green   =   (0,80,15)
blue    =   (0,0,215)

# Program Parameters
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Classic Football')
size = [700,400]
display = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Movement Parameters
pygame.key.set_repeat(0)

x = 215
y = 223
step = 50
frame_count = 0
frame_rate = 60
second = 0
minute = 5
hour = 1
side = True
hike = False

time = "1 5. 0"
score1 = "0 0"
score2 = "0 0"

lineman1x1x = 265
lineman1x1y = 174
lineman1x2x = 265
lineman1x2y = 224
lineman1x3x = 265
lineman1x3y = 274
fieldman1x1x = 465
fieldman1x1y = 174
fieldman1x2x = 365
fieldman1x2y = 224
fieldman1x3x = 565
fieldman1x3y = 274
lineman2x1x = 415
lineman2x1y = 174
lineman2x2x = 415
lineman2x2y = 224
lineman2x3x = 415
lineman2x3y = 274
fieldman2x1x = 215
fieldman2x1y = 174
fieldman2x2x = 315
fieldman2x2y = 224
fieldman2x3x = 115
fieldman2x3y = 274

playerhit = False

# Functions
def player1():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((x, y), (22, 6)), 0)

def player2():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((x+250, y), (22, 6)), 0)

def lineman1x1():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((lineman1x1x, lineman1x1y), (22, 4)), 0)
def lineman1x2():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((lineman1x2x, lineman1x2y), (22, 4)), 0)
def lineman1x3():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((lineman1x3x, lineman1x3y), (22, 4)), 0)
def fieldman1x1():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((fieldman1x1x, fieldman1x1y), (22, 4)), 0)
def fieldman1x2():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((fieldman1x2x, fieldman1x2y), (22, 4)), 0)
def fieldman1x3():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((fieldman1x3x, fieldman1x3y), (22, 4)), 0)

def lineman2x1():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((lineman2x1x, lineman2x1y), (22, 4)), 0)
def lineman2x2():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((lineman2x2x, lineman2x2y), (22, 4)), 0)
def lineman2x3():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((lineman2x3x, lineman2x3y), (22, 4)), 0)
def fieldman2x1():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((fieldman2x1x, fieldman2x1y), (22, 4)), 0)
def fieldman2x2():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((fieldman2x2x, fieldman2x2y), (22, 4)), 0)
def fieldman2x3():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, ((fieldman2x3x, fieldman2x3y), (22, 4)), 0) 




# Main Loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        # Movement
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= step
                hike = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += step

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y -= step
                hike = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y += step
                hike = True

    # Movement Restrictions
    if side == True:
        if (x < 100): x = 115
        elif (x > 565): x = 115
        if (y < 150): y = 173
        elif (y > 300): y = 273

    if side == False:
        if (x < (-150)): x = 315
        elif (x > 315): x = 315
        if (y < 150): y = 173
        elif (y > 300): y = 273      


# Game Graphics

    display.fill(green)    

    # Clock  

    hour = int(time[0])
    minute = int(time[2])
    second = int(time[5])

    if hike == True:
        frame_count += 1
        if second > 0 and frame_count == 64:
            frame_count = 0
            second -= 1
        if second == 0 and minute > 0 and frame_count == 64:
            frame_count = 0
            second = 9
            minute -= 1
        if minute == 0 and hour > 0 and frame_count == 64:
            frame_count = 0
            minute = 9
            second = 9
            hour -= 1

    time = str(hour) + " " + str(minute) + ". " + str(second)    

    # Counters
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, [150,25,400,100])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, field, [150,50,134,50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, [150,50,134,50], 2)
    pygame.draw.rect(display, field, [float(283.33333333333334),50,134,50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, [float(283.33333333333334),50,134,50], 2)
    pygame.draw.rect(display, field, [float(416.33333333333334),50,134,50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, [float(416.33333333333334),50,133,50], 2)

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 14, True, False)
    text = font.render("DOWN",True,blue)
    display.blit(text, [198, 33])
    text = font.render("FIELD POSITION",True,blue)
    display.blit(text, [305, 33])
    text = font.render("YARDS TO GO",True,blue)
    display.blit(text, [442, 33])
    text = font.render("HOME",True,blue)
    display.blit(text, [200, 105])
    text = font.render("TIME REMAINING",True,blue)
    display.blit(text, [300, 105])
    text = font.render("VISITORS",True,blue)
    display.blit(text, [456, 105])       

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('DS-Digital', 50, False, False)
    text = font.render(score1,True,red)
    display.blit(text, [188, 50])
    text = font.render(time,True,red)
    display.blit(text, [300, 50])      
    text = font.render(score2,True,red)
    display.blit(text, [453, 50])

    # Field Grid
    pygame.draw.rect(display, field, [100,150,500,150])
    for b in range(0,300,150):
        pygame.draw.line(display, white, (100,150 + b), (600,150 + b), 2)
    for a in range (0,550,50):
        pygame.draw.line(display, white, (100 + a,150), (100 + a,300), 2)    
    for a in range (0,450,50):
        pygame.draw.line(display, white, (140 + a,200), (160 + a,200), 2)
    for a in range (0,450,50):
        pygame.draw.line(display, white, (140 + a,250), (160 + a,250), 2)
    for a in range (0,980,490):
        pygame.draw.line(display, white, (100 + a,200), (110 + a,200), 2)        
    for a in range (0,980,490):
        pygame.draw.line(display, white, (100 + a,250), (110 + a,250), 2)  

    # End Zones
    pygame.draw.rect(display, blue, [80,150,21,151])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, [80,150,21,151], 2)

    pygame.draw.rect(display, blue, [600,150,20,151])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, [600,150,20,151], 2)

    # Goal Posts
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (50,200), (80,210), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (50,250), (80,240), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (70,208), (70,242), 2)

    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (650,200), (620,210), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (650,250), (620,240), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (630,208), (630,243), 2)    

    # Players




    if side == True:
        player1()
        lineman1x1()
        lineman1x2()
        lineman1x3()
        fieldman1x1()
        fieldman1x2()
        fieldman1x3()

        import random
        move = random.randint(0, 9)

        if lineman1x1x > x:
            if move == 0 or 3 or 5 or 8:
                lineman1x1x - step
            elif move == 0 or 3 or 5 or 8:
                lineman1x1x + step
        if lineman1x1y > y:
            if move == 1 or 4 or 7 or 9:
                lineman1x1y - step
            elif move == 1 or 4 or 7 or 9:
                lineman1x1y + step


        if x == lineman1x1x:
            playerhit = True


        if playerhit == True:             
                pygame.draw.rect(display, white, ((x, y), (22, 6)), 0) 






    if side == False:
        player2()
        lineman2x1()
        lineman2x2()
        lineman2x3()
        fieldman2x1()
        fieldman2x2()
        fieldman2x3()



    #FPS
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the game is supposed to work, but if you just need collision detection, you can use [`pygame.Rect`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) as players and then check if a player rect collides with the rect of another one with the [`colliderect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35002790/6220679

Comment: How do I select your comment as my answer?

Comment: You can't select a comment as an answer, but I can post one if you want. So you just needed collision detection with pygame.Rects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pygame.Rect`s for the collision detection. They are also useful to store the positions of the players and to move them.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    player1 = pg.Rect(100, 200, 50, 50)
    player2 = pg.Rect(300, 200, 50, 50)
    color1 = (0, 100, 200)
    color2 = (200, 50, 0)
    # I'd define two lists for the different teams.
    # Just put all players into these lists.
    team1 = [player1]
    team2 = [player2]
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                # Move left/right.
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player1.x += 50
                elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                    player1.x -= 50
                # Check if the player collides with an opponent.
                for opponent in team2:
                    if player1.colliderect(opponent):
                        # Do something with the players.
                        print('Collision!')


        screen.fill((40, 50, 40))
        # To draw the players you can iterate over the player rects 
        # and draw them with their corresponding color.
        for player in team2:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, color2, player)
        for player in team1:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, color1, player)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You could also use [pygame sprites and sprite groups](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13) instead of rects and list. However, you need to know how classes work first (check out chapter 12 of the linked book).